# Reading one single line using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a `currentenv.txt` file that contains a single line: `admin`

I need to read that from a batch file, now I now that I can do that in a loop, i.e.:

`for /f %%i in (currentenv.txt)` but that seems like an overkill to read one line (it'll always be one single line

Is there an easier/cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: 
`set /p _from_env=<config/currentenv.txt`

Comment: Well done! _Better advice is to protect where possible using double quotes, `Set/P "_from_env="<"config/currentenv.txt"`._